# How to display a null row between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using a view in SQL Server 2000

Table1:

```
id  z1      z2      z3      z4   type
--------------------------------------
01A 300     400     300     400  01
2B  300     400     300     500  02
3C  700     600     400     300  01
04A 500     400     800     900  01
05B 400     300     400     300  02
06  150     200     200     150  03
....
```

Table2:

```
type  value1         value2
------------------------------------    
01    0      300
01    301    500          
02    0      200
02    201    400
03
.....
```

I want to select the table1 rows based on table2 range:

Combination for table1- `max(Z1, Z2) and max(Z3, Z4)`

If Max(z1,z2)  range is less than or equal to table2 max(value2) where table1.type = table2.type
If Max(z1, z2)  range is less than or equal to table2 max(value2) where table1.type = table2.type

If z1, Z2 range less than or equal to table2 then i want to display the z1, z2 rows otherwise null
If z3, z4 range less than or equal to table2 then i want to display the z3, z4 rows otherwise null

Expected output

Table1:

```
 id  z1      z2      z3      z4   type
    --------------------------------------

01A 300     400     300     400  01 ' `Both (z1, z2), (z3, z4) rows are matching with table2 for type 01`
2B  300     400     null     null  02 ' (z1, z2) are matching, (z3, z4) rows are not matching with table2 for type 02
3C  null    null     400     300  01 ' (z1, z2) rows are not matching, (z3, z4) rows are matching with table2 for type 01
04A 500     400     null     null  01 ' (z1, z2) rows are matching, (z3, z4) rows are not matching with table2 for type 01
05B 400     300     400     300  02 ' Both (z1, z2), (z3, z4) rows are matching with table2 for type 02

....
```

Currently I'm using a view, I don't want to change to stored procedure because most of the report are using this view.

How to do it in sql..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to give the expected results. (I'd have preferred to use a CTE, but you specified 2000).

Sample data:

```
declare @T1 table (Id varchar(3) not null,z1 int not null,z2 int not null,z3 int not null,z4 int not null,type char(2) not null)
insert into @T1 (id,z1,z2,z3,z4,type) values
('01A',300,400,300,400,'01'),
('2B',300,400,300,500,'02'),
('3C',700,600,400,300,'01'),
('04A',500,400,800,900,'01'),
('05B',400,300,400,300,'02'),
('06',150,200,200,150,'03')

declare @T2 table (type char(2) not null,value1 int not null,value2 int not null)
insert into @T2 (type,value1,value2) values
('01',0,300),
('01',301,500),
('02',0,200),
('02',201,400)
```

Query:

```
select
    t1.Id,
    CASE WHEN t2.type is not null then z1 END as z1,
    CASE WHEN t2.type is not null then z2 END as z2,
    CASE WHEN t3.type is not null then z3 END as z3,
    CASE WHEN t3.type is not null then z4 END as z4,
    t1.type
from
    @T1 t1
        left join
    (select type,MAX(value2) as val2 from @T2 group by type) t2
        on
            t1.type = t2.type and
            t1.z1 <= t2.val2 and
            t1.z2 <= t2.val2
        left join
    (select type,MAX(value2) as val2 from @T2 group by type) t3
        on
            t1.type = t3.type and
            t1.z3 <= t3.val2 and
            t1.z4 <= t3.val2
where
    t2.type is not null or
    t3.type is not null
```

Result:

```
Id   z1          z2          z3          z4          type
---- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----
01A  300         400         300         400         01
2B   300         400         NULL        NULL        02
3C   NULL        NULL        400         300         01
04A  500         400         NULL        NULL        01
05B  400         300         400         300         02
```

I'm not sure what the relevance of your question title was, the verbiage in the middle is quite confusing, and I made a guess at the final `WHERE` clause since the `06` row seems to disappear.